# How to get the distinct count by name and date in excel

Tags: excel

###### Sample Data

| Name | case# | datereceived | Date1 | Date2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tina | 10 | 1/2/2021 | 1/22/2022 | 1/2/2023 | 345 |
| Tina | 10 | 1/4/2021 | 1/23/2022 | 1/3/2023 | 345 |
| Tina | 11 | 1/5/2021 | 1/23/2022 | 1/6/2023 | 348 |
| Tasha | 11 | 1/3/2022 | 1/24/2022 | 4/23/203 | 454 |

1. I am using this formula in the `Result` column:

   ```
    =IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date2])- 1/(1/Details[Date1]),"")
   ```
2. I need another formula to get the distinct count of `case#` and `datereceived` by `person`
3. Then I have to calculate the result of dividing the `Result` values by the results from #2 above.

###### Sample Pivot Summary

| Name | year | month | Average ( Result / Unique cases) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tina | 2021 | jan | (345+345+348)/2 |

Explanation: (denominator) Tina in Jan 2021 had received 2 distinct cases.
(Numerator) should be sum of values of the result column by name and datereceived year/month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Manual Calculation

If you prefer to manually create a formula then this should work.
I used a lot of named functions to make it easier to follow.

```
=LET(
    name,Details[Name], start,CELL("row",name),
    rec,Details[datereceived], case,Details[case'#],
    diff,IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date2])-1/(1/Details[Date1]),),
    yr,YEAR(rec), mon,MONTH(rec),
    rows, MAP(name, case, yr, mon,  LAMBDA(n,c,y,m,
        MATCH(1, (n=name) * (y=yr) * (m=mon), 0) + start)),
        calc, LAMBDA(col, MAP(UNIQUE(rows), LAMBDA(r,
          LET(x,FILTER(HSTACK(name,case,yr,mon,diff), (rows=r)*(diff>0),""),
            IFERROR(IF(col="avg", SUM(INDEX(x,, 5))/ROWS(UNIQUE(INDEX(x,, 2))),
            IF(col=2, ROWS(UNIQUE(INDEX(x,,col))), INDEX(x, 1, col))),))))),
    avg, calc("avg"), arr,FILTER(HSTACK(calc(1), calc(3), calc(4), calc(2), avg),LEN(avg)),
    VSTACK({"Name","Year","Month","Cases","Avg. Days/Case"},
        SORTBY(arr, INDEX(arr,,2) & INDEX(arr,,3), -1)))
```

#### Explanation

- `rows` stores a list containing the row numbers of unique combinations of `Name, Year, Month` (first combination it finds that isn't a duplicate)
- `calc` returns one of `Name`, `Year`, `Month`, `Cases` (unique count), or `Avg. Days/Case` for each of those unique combinations - `calc` determines what to return based on whether it is passed a column number or the string "avg"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly, and assuming you're allowed to add new columns you can do something like this:

| Year | Month | Numer | Temp1 | Denom | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 1038 | 0.5 | 2 | 519 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1038 | 0.5 | 2 | 519 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1038 | 1 | 2 | 519 |
| 2022 | 1 | 454 | 1 | 1 | 454 |

Where:

- `Year = YEAR([@datereceived])`
- `Month = MONTH([@datereceived])`
- `Numer =SUMIFS([Result],[Name],[@Name],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month])` # Just does the sum i.e. Numerator of your result
- `Temp =1/COUNTIFS([Name],[@Name],[case'#],[@[case'#]],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month])` # Temporary column to calculate Denominator
- `Denom =SUMIFS([Temp1],[Name],[@Name],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month])` # Denominator for your Result = Number of unique cases
- `Output = =[@Numer]/[@Denom]`

Now this has duplicate rows for Output, so based on your use case you can make it similar to your sample output by removing duplicates, vlookup, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Numer =SUMIFS([Result],[Name],[@Name],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month])  ? Result column is a derived column how do I call that column in formula? All the other columns are in the details table. Example: I can call them as details[name]. [Name],[@Name] why there are two columns repeating like this ? I didn't understand. Can you please modify the formula in a way that  I can use in excel.

Comment: The pivot summary format which is shown in the question, for that I will create a pivot on the data in excel. Is it possible to show a formulas next to result column to do all these calculations ?I can add any number of calculated fields

Comment: I tried Numer =SUMIFS([Result],[Name],[@Name],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month]). This is not working. I am getting an error message as there's a problem with the formula

Comment: I am assuming you are using a Excel table here [version 365 or 2021 onwards] and column names are consistent; if not does replacing the references with actual array ranges work for you?

Comment: First,  I need the calculated field to get the distinct count of case# by name and datereceived year and month. Name is also a calculated field which has a reference on table arguments. Here result in the sample data is the calculated field which has reference on the table array.

Comment: "First, I need the calculated field to get the distinct count of case#" Yup this is the "Denom" column in the table. 
Can you expand on what error you're getting when you use the formula and if replacing to actual array references fixes it or not?